# StreamWriter writes all data into 1 Column in CSV file

Tags: c#, csv, streamwriter

```
using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText("D:\\Data.csv"))
{  
      foreach (var test in data)
      {
          sw.WriteLine(test.A.ToString()+','+test.B.ToString());
      }
}
```

test.A and test.B are listed in column A of CSV file.I want them to be in the separate columns.

Comment: Hi. What does it mean that they are in the same column? Like you open the file in excel and it renders the data in one cell? Try adding space after the comma maybe?

Comment: you can select delimiter, if you open excel go to data and select from text/csv

Comment: Adding space does nothing.

Comment: Separate values by ';'

Comment: This question has nothing to do with c#, it has to do with how to get Excel (or whatever spread sheets app you are using) to delaminate values. You could have also created a .csv file in a folder, opened it in a text editor, added the content in some format (a line or 2 is plenty) and then opened it in the app. Once you figured out what works by default in that app you could have formatted the output accordingly in c#.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your delimiter to `semicolon` - it will separate your headers into different columns when you open the CSV file via Excel.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue: I was able to write to a .txt or .csv with commas as the separators, but in Excel and other apps (python's Pandas) it wasn't being recognized as separate columns properly, my data was all in one column.

I solved this by modifying the Encoding to utf-8:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding?view=net-6.0

This is the default for SW but you might have mistakenly changed this elsewhere.